# NullReferenceException in lable content

Tags: c#, wpf

when I try to change the value of the lalbe it always give me null 
this is my 
xmal

```
<Label Content="text" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="211" Width="424" FontSize="45">
```

this is 
my code

```
 var lblText = sender as Label;
 lblText.Content = "TEST";
```

I always get 'System.NullReferenceException'  error

Comment: if sender is not a Label, then `as` returns `null`. In which function do you call the code?

Comment: I'm calling it in  SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e) method

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are calling your code in an event handler (for example a button click). In this case the sender is the `button` and so the `as` operator will return `null`

Add a name to the label:

```
<Label Name="myLabel" ... />
```

and use it like this:

```
myLabel.Content = "TEST";
```

By the way: **Normally in WPF you don't modify the GUI directly but use `DataBinding` instead**

Comment: from where can I call it I'm calling it from SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e) method that check the user speech

Comment: You can call it from wherever you want but `sender` is not the label but some SpeechRecognizer object in this case.

Comment: I tried calling it outside the method label.Content = "text" but I got red line .. btw what is dataBinding

Comment: Just add `Name="myLabel"` in the XAML in your Label and then you can use `myLabel` to access the label directly. You do not need the `sender`. `DataBinding` is a concept for decoupling the GUI from the logic but there are many articles about it, just search it on google.

Comment: Thank you I did this         <Label x:Name="lblStatus"  HorizontalAlignment="Left">